# calling single javascript function for each php variable fetched from database, multiple countdown program

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to get a multiple countdown system, event day and minutes being fetched from database. There can be many such events. After getting the event date, i pass this values to a javascript function which on client side runs for every 1 sec using the setTimout function. This works fine for one event. However for many events how do i achieve the same functionality. i.e i want to run the javascript function for each event.

I am getting some php variables from database. eg

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$a = $row['day'];
$b = $row['minutes'];
```

}

Now i need to pass all this values inside a javascript function.
If there were only one event, i could directly pass the php values. But for multiple events i am confused as to what to do. I tried using a javascript function inside the while loop, but i get function not defined error, and that is obvious because php is run before javascrip. Any logic, or help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: write your multievent javascript and make it work first. PHP has nothing to do here

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, But i am getting the event date from php. And am using this values in javascript function. If i get the event date, i find the current time, then find the difference. After getting the difference i pass the values to javascript function and call it every 1 second to display as a countdown.

Comment: it doesn't matter. you are writing whole JS program using PHP. **but how the hell can you make it with PHP if you don't even know how it should look?** Before doing something, one should know what they want to get. So, you have to write your JS first, make it working, and only then write a PHP script which will print out the same text you wrote by hand

Comment: ok, col. I get your point. Thanks for a quick reply. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you PHP, first build your data array. It does not matter how you do it, but in the end, it may look something like :

```
$data = array(
   array('day' => 1, 'minutes' => '15'),
   array('day' => 0, 'minutes' => '45'),
   array('day' => 15, 'minutes' => 52'),
   // etc.
);
```

Then (still with PHP, create a Javascript function like :

```
var data = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;  // encode your PHP data into JSON notation
var interval = setInterval(function() {
   for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      // do something with your data
      // data[i].day   ... data[i].minutes ... etc.
   };
}, 1000);   // run every 1 sec
```

Note that the more data you have, the slower `setInterval` will execute. Just remember that Javascript is slow compared to other languages. Also, `setInterval` is preferable over `setTimeout` in your case to avoid stacking up your calls in the long run, therefore you should not rely on `setTimeout` nor `setInterval` for a 1 second interval, but you should have a variable to calculate the exact time span between each calls.

Something like;

```
var last_time = new Date().getTime();
```

then, inside your `setInterval` function, get how long the last function was called since last time (or for the first time, since page load)

```
var cur_time = new Date().getTime();
var timespan = (cur_time - last_time) / 1000; // millis > sec
last_time = cur_time; // update last_time
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't run N functions in JS, run one that will do N operations. Pass the values from PHP as a JS Array, and within your Timeout handler iterate over that array. Your JS would look something like this:

```
// This line generated by PHP:
var thingies = ["Thingy 1", "Thingy 2", "Thingy3"];

// This is static JS:
function thingy() {
  for (var i in thingies) {
    processThingy(thingies[i];
  }
  setTimeout(thingy, 1000);
}
```

Or, alternately, you could load `thingies` by AJAX later; the principle is the same.

Comment: Hi amadan, i'll write first the js program as col suggested and make it working. Yes i can use php values as js array. Thanks for a quick tip.

Comment: Hi @Amadan, is there any more concrete code example, or does this technique have a name?